# C#: Writing to 'x' storage then dump to file

Tags: c#, file, logging, filestream

I am trying to build a simple logging class without causing too many problems across multiple classes when accessing the same file.

I have several classes that will write to the same 'LOG' file but I was wondering if there was some sort of buffer I could write to that I could dump once I finished processing the information.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Logging
{
    class Logging
    {
        private StreamWriter writer;

        private Logging(string _path, bool _append)
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(_path, _append);
        }

        public void Log(string _text)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(_text);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use existing code like log4net.

Comment: Hi, I looked at that but I am trying to keep it as simple as possible. As you can see from the code above there is not much more I would add to it other than this "buffer".

Comment: 1. Define a queue as the buffer 2. Synchronize accesses(read and write) to the buffer using locks etc... 3. Modify your logger to write to buffer instead of file. 4. Create a new thread that reads from buffer and writes to file. This is as simple as I can think of.

Comment: Standard case of trying to solve a problem you don't have.  StreamWriter already has a buffer.